# Saving hasMany relationship with form

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have some trouble when saving my form with hasMany relationship. Everything works fine when I do update existing productVariants. The problem comes when I want to create new product or update existing by adding new variants to each. What do I want to reach? As you can see all my productVariants are displayed in table. I would want to create new productVariant by hitting a button that invokes 'addVariant' action and dynamically adds new row to existing table with possibility of filling inputs. All new variants should be sent to backend when I submit the form. Could you give me any tips or provide some twiddle? I'm quite new to EmberJS and JS in general and that kind of help would definitely decrease my efforts during learning. I place some code below.

Models:

```
export default DS.Model.extend(Validations, {
  uniqueId: DS.attr('string'),
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  defaultPrice: fragment('price'),
  venue: DS.belongsTo('venue'),
  deleted: DS.attr('boolean'),
  productType: DS.attr('string'),

  productCategory: DS.belongsTo('product-category', {async: false}),
  productVariants: DS.hasMany('product-variant', {async: false}),
});

export default DS.Model.extend({
  uniqueId: DS.attr('string'),
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  fullName: DS.attr('string'),
  price: fragment('price'),
  weighted: DS.attr('boolean'),
  openPrice: DS.attr('boolean'),

  product: DS.belongsTo('product')
});
```

Product form:

```
export default Component.extend({
  store: service(),

  categories: computed(function(){
    return this.store.findAll('product-category', {
    });
  }),

  init() {
    this._super(...arguments);
    this.productTypes = ['PRODUCT_WITH_RECEPTURE', 'SET_AS_ONE_ITEM', 'SET_AS_SEPARATE_ITEMS', 'PIZZA'];
    this.currencies = ['PLN', 'EUR', 'USD'];
  },


  actions: {
    chooseCategory(category){
      let product = this.get('model');
      product.set('productCategory', category);
      this.set('productCategory', category);
    },

    chooseProductType(option){
      let product = this.get('model');
      product.set('productType', option);
      this.set('productType', option);
    },

    chooseCurrency(currency){
      let product = this.get('model');
      product.set('defaultPrice.currency', currency)
      this.set('currency', currency)
    },

    saveProduct(param){
      this.sendAction('action', param);
    }
  }
});
```

And its component:

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    {{#validated-input model=model valuePath='name' placeholder='Nazwa'}}{{/validated-input}}
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    {{#validated-input model=model valuePath='defaultPrice.amount' placeholder='Koszt'}}{{/validated-input}}
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Kategoria</label>
      {{#power-select
        selected=model.productCategory
        options=categories
        onchange=(action "chooseCategory") as |productCategory|}}
        {{productCategory.name}}
      {{/power-select}}
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Waluta</label>
      {{#power-select
        options=currencies
        selected=model.defaultPrice.currency
        onchange=(action "chooseCurrency") as |currency|}}
        {{currency}}
      {{/power-select}}
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Typ produktu</label>
      {{#power-select
        options=productTypes
        selected=model.productType
        onchange=(action "chooseProductType") as |productType|}}
        {{productType}}
      {{/power-select}}
    </div>
  </div>
  {{#product/product-variant-form item=model}}{{/product/product-variant-form}}
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" {{action 'saveProduct' model}}>Zapisz</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Product variant form:

```
<legend>Warianty</legend>
<table class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Nazwa</th>
    <th>Cena</th>
    <th>Dostępność</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  {{#each item.productVariants as |productVariant|}}
    <tr>
      <th>{{input type="text" value=productVariant.fullName class="form-control"}}</th>
      <th>{{input type="text" value=productVariant.price.amount class="form-control"}}</th>
      <th class="center-check-box">{{input type="checkbox" checked=productVariant.openPrice class="form-control"}}</th>
    </tr>
  {{/each}}
  <button {{action 'addVariant'}}>Dodaj wariant</button>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And its component:

```
export default Component.extend({

  store: service(),

  init() {
    this._super(...arguments);
    this.variants = [];
  },

  actions: {
    addVariant() {
      let product = this.get('model');
      console.log(product);
      let variant = this.store.createRecord('product-variant', {
        name: '',
        price: this.get('store').createRecord('price')
      });
      this.get('variants').pushObject(variant);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: You may want to try out the addon ember-data-save-relationships

Comment: It seems like you don't associate the created `product-variant` with the `product`. When it comes to saving you should have in mind that an one-to-many relationship is not saved on the many-side per default: https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember-data/3.7/classes/DS.JSONAPISerializer/methods/shouldSerializeHasMany?anchor=shouldSerializeHasMany

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you aren't associating your variant with your product and you're not saving them afterwards. There's an [example of this in the Ember documentation](https://guides.emberjs.com/v3.4.0/models/relationships/#toc_creating-records). Should be something like this:

```
let product = this.get('model');
let variant = this.store.createRecord('product-variant', {
  name: '',
  price: this.get('store').createRecord('price')
});

product.get('productVariants').pushObject(variant);

variant.save().then(function () {
  product.save();
});
```